# Send multiline value with Github Actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions

I have a pipeline in GHA, one of the steps sends a multiline string created in a previous step "message" to a custom action "send mail" that I am writing.

````
- name: send mail
  id: mail
  uses: internal/send-mail@main
  with:
    subject: "{{ github.event.pull_request.tittle }}"
    mail_body: "\n```\n${{ steps.message.outputs.stdout }}\n```\n"
````

The custom action receives the multiline value as input correctly but I facing an error while trying to assign it as env variable.

```
name: send mail action
inputs:
  subject:
  mail_body:

runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - name: set env variables
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "MAIL_SUBJECT=${{ inputs.subject }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "MAIL_BODY=${{ inputs.mail_body }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

At this point, I get this error:

> stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

> TERM environment variable not set

How could I keep the multiline value for MAIL_BODY in the custom GHA?

My goal is to read the MAIL_BODY variable from a python script and continue the flow.

Comment: I think I found the solution to the problem, I removed the "MAIL_BODY" assignment in the "set env variables" step and added a local environment variable in the other step that executes the python command. After that I had no errors